# How to create a presentation using .svg files representing each slide

Tags: animation, svg, latex, beamer

This question is motivated by the answer given in this question

[Using the animate package without adobe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235139/using-the-animate-package-without-adobe)

I want to create latex beamer presentations without relying on adobe, as it is a pain.

I followed the instructions given in the post's answer, and when compiling the given example code, the output were 4 .svg files, and I have no idea on what to do with them.

Something tells me they should be embedded into an html file that produce a slide-presentation, but I'm a complete noob in html and I've not been able to find an answer on how to achieve this.

Comment: You don't need any additional wrapper like an html file. Simply open the first svg file in your browser and use the little arrows at the top right for navigation. They automatically link to the next slide.

Comment: omg, I cannot believe I wasted 1 hour looking for a solution for this.

Thank you ! Feel free to write this as an answer so I can declare it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional wrapper for the individual .svg files is necessary. Simply open the first .svg file in your browser and use the little arrows at the top right for navigation. They automatically link to the next slide.

[image]